# Adding Q_OBJECT macro gives "unresolved external error" in QThread inherited class

Tags: c++, qt

I have QThread inherited class and when i add a Q_OBJECT macro, it gives unresolved external error. (I've included QObject and QThread).

```
class TCustomThread: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TCustomThread(QObject *parent=0);

public slots:
    void testSlot();
}
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Are you planning on re-writing how Qt manages threads? If not, and you're inheriting from QThread, you're doing it wrong: http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: If you're going to use QThread, you should read this: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: I've clean and rebuilt it but it doesn't works :( . It's too weird.

Comment: I've re-implemented QThread and overrided its "run()" method and it worked like a charm but when i add Q_OBJECT macro it gives me error

Comment: Are you using QtCreator? Clean and Rebuild do not run qmake again.

Comment: It looks like moc is not being run. Or if moc is being run the generated sources are not being included in the build.

Comment: You should note that if you put slots in a `QThread` subclass, they won't be executed in the thread it's managing, but in the thread your `TCustomThread` object was created. More about this [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#details).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case this error may accrue only if moc tool didn't create meta data for this class.
This can happen in two cases:

- file dependencies are broken so you have to run `qmake` and/or clean project (`make clean`).
- moc tool is not instructed to generate those data, for example you are missing entry in pro file: `HEADERS += tcustomthread.h`

I'm assuming that you are using pro file, if you are using other build manager you have to just add missing entry respective to this `HEADERS += tcustomthread.h`.

Comment: if you change the pro file you need to run qmake again

Comment: For others encountering this issue, this was caused when I created a new class (.h and .cpp files) outside my project directory and forgot to check "add to project" during creation.